# TiledMapTileLayer wont cast from TileLayer

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I'm trying to get cells from a tile layer in libgdx (for a tiled map). A lot of examples I see say to cast a layer to TiledMapTileLayer, but this doesn't work.

```
TiledMap tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("start.tmx");
TiledMapTileLayer obsLayer = (TileMapTileLayer) tiledMap.getLayers().get("obs");
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapLayer cannot be cast to com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer
    at net.myname.mygame.Game.create(Game.java:66)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

My guess is the library was updated to work differently, but I don't see any examples doing things in a new way. Anyone know what to do?

I'm using libgdx 1.9.9

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, I guess my map got reverted accidentally. Was using a object layer before but changed it to a tile layer. Changing to a tile layer instead of an object layer makes it work.